# Why pawns starting at chessboard squares $(1,1)$ and $(8,8)$ that move orthogonally at each step will never swap positions?

Tags: markov-chains, puzzle, invariance, chessboard

Let's say we have a chessboard (i.e an $8×8$ grid). Let's assume each cell is identified by two coordinates (integer numbers) ranging from $1$ to $8$.

Assume to have a red pawn in position $(1, 1)$ and a green one in position $(8, 8)$. In other words, they are in the opposite corners of the board.
At each turn, the two pawns move (randomly) simultaneously. However, they can only move up, down, right and left with no diagonal moves allowed.

I am interested in finding whether or not the two pawns will eventually exchange cells. By exchanging cell I mean that the red pawn goes from $(x_1, y_1)$ to $(x_2, y_2)$ and the green one from $(x_2, y_2)$ to $(x_1, y_1)$ in the same turn.

By computer simulation I saw this is never happening. I wonder why is that the case.

If we allow diagonal moves, the two pawns will eventually exchange cells (according to my simulation) in an average of $48.6$ movements.

Comment: If the red pawn follows the path $(1,1)\to (1,2)\to\cdots\to (1,8)\to (2,8)\to\cdots (8,8)$ and the green pawn follows the path $(8,8)\to (8,7)\to\cdots\to (8,1)\to (7,1)\to\cdots (1,1)$, won't they be in opposite corners ?

Comment: @SathvikAcharya We want them to stand next to one another and exchange places in a single move.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: A chessboard has colors on it. Look at the colors of the squares that the pawns are on.

Comment: Never thought to look at the colored board. Basically, they are always on the same color every turn. Hence, they cannot exchange cells as that would require them to be on different colors. Is that the reason?

Comment: Very nice hint!

Comment: @YodaAndFriends That's exactly the reason. Or rather, it's _a_ reason.

Comment: Does this mean that your analysis is invalid if the chessboard is first bleached to remove the color from all of the squares?

Comment: @user2661923 The chessboard coloring is in the eye of the beholder.